# Oracle SQL developer bug

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a table with the create table GUI. It doesn't let me change the table names. Most of them are still on 'COLUMN'.

I tried editing using the GUI but the names revert back to 'COLUMN'.
It doesn't always automatically create a DDL. when it doesn't, it doesn't change/edit my table.

I've tried installing a different version but mlno luck.

Comment: Which version is a "different version"? I guess you should install the **latest**. I can't reproduce what you're saying on SQL Developer 21.2.1 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd68K.png)

Comment: I had the latest version, but still. I asked my friend if he can reproduce the problem everything works fine for him.

Comment: It's a known bug, yes.